# Get way Id from OSRM matching service

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, osrm

I am using OSRM match service and getting response

But i am not able to get any reliable way to convert the response into set of way ids car traveled through (especially which will work at intersections)

Answer (score 2):

Way IDs aren't available but you can get node IDs by adding `annotations=nodes` option to your request, i.e. http://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407;13.428555,52.523219?annotations=nodes

The annotation object is documented on http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.15.2/api/#annotation-object

Comment: Adding annotation nodes gives node ids and still you need to decide n way id. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think you'll have to use either openstreetmap or overpass data/API to convert nodes to ways.